# MySQL 8 slow Query cause deprecated?

Tags: mysql

I find this query and that takes 20 seconds for few rows...

```
SELECT DISTINCT(BINARY `meta_key`) as meta_key_binary, `meta_key`
FROM wp_postmeta
ORDER BY `meta_key` ASC
```

Is that deprecated in mysql 8? How to change it for mysql 8 than?
Or any idea why that is so slow?

I cant find something nearly same for mysql 8

Comment: Is there an error or something, or just a long run?

Comment: @PaulT. Its just really slow and i read something that BINARY in distrinct is deprecated on mysql8? but i dont find something same

Comment: @Horaciux no :( that doesnt give me binary back...

Comment: got back the same as meta_key alone

Comment: What part of it do you think might be deprecated? It seems like a perfectly ordinary query.

Comment: Does `meta_key` have an index?

Comment: What happens if you leave out `BINARY`? That's probably preventing it from using the index.

Comment: BTW, your use of parentheses suggests that you think `DISTINCT` is a function that only applies to a particular column. It's a keyword that applies to the entire SELECT list.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `BINARY` conversion operator is probably preventing use of an index for your query.

You could add a virtual column to the table with the binary value of `meta_key` and index that.

```
ALTER TABLE wp_postmeta 
    ADD COLUMN meta_key_binary VARCHAR(100) AS (BINARY meta_key),
    ADD INDEX (meta_key_binary, meta_key);
```

Replace `(100)` with the correct length of `meta_key` from the original table schema.

Comment: It's 255, which wreaks havoc with 5.5 - 5.6 when using utf8mb4.

Answer (score 0):

> ----- 2021-10-19 8.0.27 General Availability -- -- Important Change -----

> The [BINARY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#operator_binary) operator is now deprecated, and subject to removal in a future release of MySQL. Use of BINARY now causes a warning. Use [CAST(... AS BINARY)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) instead.

See Barmar's Comment on parentheses

For improved performance of WP, especially when using `postmeta`:  [*WP Index Improvements*](https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/)